# Compiling Marlin 2.0

Tags: marlin, firmware

I've just finished building a new printer and I wanted to take advantage of a 32 bits board I ordered some time ago. The board is an MKS SBase 1.3

I've been researching the Smoothiware firmware but somehow I'm not convinced by it yet. One of the things pulling me off is the Z-Probe behavior. On my Arduino-Marlin 1.1.8 machine, I have a probe which serves as both probe and Z-Endstop without a problem and very elegant implemented whereas on Smoothie, it's not so trivial as far as I've seen.

Anyway, there is a branch of Marlin which is not yet for release but for testing and it supports 32 bits boards, being mine mentioned above one of them:

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/bugfix-2.0.x

I have yet to find some documentation explaining how to install it. The closest thing I found is a thread on their GitHub "forum":

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/8131

It seems that you have to build the project to create a firmware.bin file which you can copy to the microSD card and it will flash automatically to the board... again, no "official" documentation found.

I've tried the steps described in this thread but I'm not able to compile for my board as it gives an error no matter what:

```
Marlin/src/gcode/eeprom/M500-M504.cpp:74:5: error: no matching function for call to 'MarlinSettings::report(bool, int16_t&)'
```

Has somebody successfully compiled this firmware? Is there something I might be doing wrong?

I'm on a macOS machine, using Atom as editor with the Platformio-IDE installed.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve your issue? Does it still not compile? Is there a released version of Marlin that supports 32 bit boards yet? I have just downloaded it from the first link, running on OSX 10.8.5 and Arduino IDE 1.8.6 and it compiled first time. Maybe I have different compile settings or `#define`s or maybe I have missed the point of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the solution on Marlin's GitHub:

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/9155

but it might have been solved without having to hack the file since then.

Comment: This is a Link Only Answer. If the link dies, this answer becomes worthless, so it would be nice to fix it by giving us an explanation what to do here.

Comment: Could you include the line that, apparently, needs fixing?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Marlin 2.0 bugfix for several months with no issues on my RAMPS 1.4 based printer. Installing it is the same as any other printer firmware, or rather, uploading any Arduino sketch. In fact, rather than searching "how to upload Marlin Firmware" you should instead search "How to upload an Arduino Sketch" as most printers are Arduino powered and the process is the same as making a simple LED blink program, granted the source code is MUCH bigger. The quick & dirty is: Download and install the latest Arduino IDE and make sure your board is recognized by following instructions for your board. In the Marlin directory from the downloaded firmware, open the .ino file in Arduino IDE. On the tabs above, you will see Configuration.H and Configuration_adv.h those are the 2 files to edit, and ONLY 2 unless you are familiar with what you are doing, plus Marlin 2.0 redid the file layout so you shouldn't get confused by 20+ other files open also as in 1.x. The comments give you a good idea of what to change & google will help with the rest. Once done, click on Compile & Upload in the Arduino tools, and done.